# Neo4j ETL jdbc SQL Server driver

Tags: sql-server, neo4j, etl

I'm working with Neo4j desktop. I successfully installed the ETL tool but on the database configuration, I can see only the Mysql and portage default.

I downloaded the SQL Server driver and unzipped it into my active database lib directory, but the SQL Server database type option did not appear on the menu.

Please advice
Tal

Answer (score 0):

Tal, currently the sql-server support only works with the command line tool.

Please follow the instructions there:

https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-etl/#neo4j-etl-cli

Make sure to use the correct JDBC URL for SQL Server.

Here is a Docker example for SQL Server

https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-etl/#_microsoft_sql

Comment: Hi thanks
This is very strange since at the intreduction there is a link for SQL SERVER DRIVER
https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-etl/#neo4j-etl-cli